# Show message before long operation

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, label

I am working on windows mobile application. There is a call for webservice that takes several seconds to execute. I am trying to display message before it runs.

```
lblSearchMessage.Text = "Please wait...";
var info = proxy.FindProfiles();
lblSearchMessage.Text = "Completed";
```

The problem that I don't see "Please wait" message. When it runs, the label still clear till request is completed and I finally see only "Completed" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this ...

```
lblSearchMessage.Text = "Please wait...";
Application.DoEvents(); 
var info = proxy.FindProfiles();
lblSearchMessage.Text = "Completed";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `BackgroundWorker` or `Task` or `await` feature of C# (depends on which dot net framework version you are using) for delegating the long running task to background thread. In the main thread update the UI and it will reflect change immediately. You should not do the long running task in the main thread because it blocks the UI and gives user a bad impression and experience.

Take a look at [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class. It also has a simple tutorial which will make it clear how you can use it in your application.

Before starting background worker do

`lblSearchMessage.Text = "Please wait...";`

and once the background work is complete do

`lblSearchMessage.Text = "Completed";`

Comment: Thank you for usefull information, unfortunately BackgroundWorker isn't supported by Compact Framework. Tried to use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem but it complicates my code that already so complex.